# MySQL regex for Timezone format

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am implementing regex to evaluate data in multiple fields,
Currently need MySql regex to evaluate Timezone formate (2018-04-02T10:13:00)
i have tried regex like `%Y-%m-%d T %H:%i:%s` but it does not work.

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d T %H:%i:%s` (something similar) would work with `Str_to_date()` and `Date_format()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
'^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$'
```

However pattern matching does not guarantee that the date is valid e.g. `2018-02-29T00:00:00` (leap year) or `2018-04-31T00:00:00` (31 days in April).

Answer (score 1):

What you write is not a Regex. A regex would look like `....-..-..T..:..:..` in its simplest form, or maybe `(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)` in a more sophisticated way (only digits allowed, have groups to make the regex engine extract the components.

What you probably are looking for is a formatting for the MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT()` either to enter data in a given format or to get the mout of the database in a given format.

Alas, you don't tell us more of the details, so I can only direct you [to the relevant manual sections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT str_to_date('2018-04-02T10:13:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2018-04-02T10:13:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-04-02 10:13:00                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But... If the string ends with '-07:00' to indicate a timezone, that gets messier.  See `CONVERT_TZ` and some extra parsing.